# Explicitly showing error messages when page initially loads

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label></mat-label>
  <input [required] = "isMandatory? true:false" placeholder="Just a placeholder">
  <mat-error *ngIf="isMandatory">mandatory field</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The above code is working fine and showing the error message when the textbox gets dirty or in focus. Now, I am trying to show before hand when the page loads initially.

```
<input [required] = "isMandatory? true:false" placeholder="Just a placeholder"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur' }">
```

Tried above approach with no luck. Is there any way to show error messages when form initially loads? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to add the following code inside `ngOnInit()`:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    // FormControl or FormGroup initialization code
    // ....................................


    this.yourControl.markAsTouched();

    // OR, if you want for the whole formGroup (and your're using at leat Angular 8)

    this.yourFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
}
```

This should do the trick and show the client side errors (required in your case) upfront.

Comment: I am not using FormControl or FormGroup initialization. I am using plain textbox

Comment: Since you're using `<mat-form-field>` I was expecting that all this is part of a '<form>' control, and that you're using either a formControl or a formGroup for doing the data binding. Are you using `[(ngModel)]` instead on the `<input>` element? It would be helpful btw if you can share a relevant snippet of your class code.